# To Display Output in Column wise

Tags: sql

I am running below query.

```
select to_char(cdts,'HH24'), count(id)) from tbl_log where acmd = 'Add' and trunc(cdts) = trunc(sysdate -1) and astat = '14'
group by to_char(cdts, 'HH24')
order by to_char(cdts, 'HH24')
```

The output is:

```
Hours   Count
01  1
04  1
07  1
08  4
09  41
10  174
11  91
12  220
13  241
14  195
15  228
16  221
17  185
18  20
19  15
20  8
21  4
22  4
23  1
```

Similarly i am trying to get in the below format. Can anyone help us how i can get the same.
Basically when i tried sysdat -3.. it is giving in row wise.. but i want to group by dates..

```
Hours   21st March  20th March  19th March
01  1   0   0
04  1   1   2
07  1   4   10
08  4   24  16
09  41  16  84
10  174 18  106
11  91  18  140
12  220 96  170
13  241 146 152
14  195 127 178
15  228 123 225
16  221 110 168
17  185 13  30
18  20  13  4
19  15  19  11
20  8   3   3
21  4   0   0
22  4   0   0
23  1   0   0
```

Comment: pls, convert your TEXT in CODE.

Answer (score 0):

Following is one query, which I have prepared for my project, you can use same logic.Hope it helps to you.

```
;With CTE as 
(
    select  Hours
        ,tDateDay
        ,Cnt
)
select Hours,
    Isnull([1],0) as dt1,Isnull([2],0) as dt2,Isnull([3],0) as dt3,Isnull([4],0) as dt4,Isnull([5],0) as dt5,
    Isnull([6],0) as dt6,Isnull([7],0) as dt7,Isnull([8],0) as dt8,Isnull([9],0) as dt9,Isnull([10],0) as dt10,
    Isnull([11],0) as dt11,Isnull([12],0) as dt12,Isnull([13],0) as dt13,Isnull([14],0) as dt14,Isnull([15],0) as dt15,
    Isnull([16],0) as dt16,Isnull([17],0) as dt17,Isnull([18],0) as dt18,Isnull([19],0) as dt19,Isnull([20],0) as dt20,
    Isnull([21],0) as dt21,Isnull([22],0) as dt22,Isnull([23],0) as dt23,Isnull([24],0) as dt24,Isnull([25],0) as dt25,
    Isnull([26],0) as dt26,Isnull([27],0) as dt27,Isnull([28],0) as dt28,Isnull([29],0) as dt29,Isnull([30],0) as dt30,
    Isnull([31],0) as dt31
 from CTE
pivot (sum(Cnt) for tDateDay in([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],
[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31])) as DayDate 
order by Hours asc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but i am getting missing expression errors.. if am adding first(;), it is saying invalid character.